# ¿Qué le falta al codigo en R?

Tags: r

```
B <- 1e4

f <- function(x, y) (x*(1-x))^y

x <- matrix(0, B, 2)

x[1, ] <- c(1/2, 1/2)

for(i in 2:B) {

  u <- runif(1, 0, f(x[i-1, 1], x[i-1, 2]))

  tmp <- sqrt(1-4*u^(1/x[i-1, 2]))

  x[i, 1] <- runif(1, (1-tmp)/2, (1+tmp)/2)

  u <- runif(1, 0, f(x[i, 1], x[i-1, 2]))

  x[i, 2] <- runif(1, 0, 

                min(1, log(u)/log(x[i, 1]*(1-x[i, 1]))))

}

draw.hist <- function(x) {

  K <- double.integral(f, high=c(1, 1))

  z <- seq(0, 1, length=250)

  y <- 0*z

  f1 <- function(x, y) f(y, x)
  for(i in 1:250)

    y[i] <- integrate(f1, 0, 1, y=z[i])$value

  par(mfrow=c(1, 2))

  hist(x[, 1], 50, freq=FALSE, main="", 

       xlab="x", ylab="")

  lines(z, y/K, lwd=2, col="blue")

  y <- 0*z

  for(i in 1:250)

    y[i] <- integrate(f, 0, 1, y=z[i])$value

  hist(x[, 2], 50, freq=FALSE, main="", 

       xlab="y", ylab="")

  lines(z, y/K, lwd=2, col="blue")

}

draw.hist(x[-c(1:1000),])
```

Lo que pasa es:

> ¿Que le falta la funcion double.integral?

La he buscado pero no la he encontrado nada, así que quisiera saber cual es el error. El codigo es en R

Comment: Le fata exactamente lo que dices, la función `double.integral()` o forma parte de un paquete que no has cargado o es código que te falta. Tal vez esto: https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/pracma/versions/1.9.9/topics/integral2 te sirva

Comment: la pregunta no es clara. Qué error encuentras al usar tu código? Qué debería hacer en su lugar?

Comment: según veo la función no existe en R.